# How can I change the name of a partition, as it appears in the Unity Launcher?

Tags: unity, partitioning, launcher

I have separate partitions in my Ubuntu. For example I have named those partitions as "Academic","Entertainment". Their named are displayed as "Academic","Entertainment" in their properties popup tab. But when they are displayed in Ubuntu Launcher, they are displayed their size instead of  their name, how to change the appearance name?

As you can see below, when I mouse over that particular folder in Ubuntu Launcher, they pop up their size instead of the name:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as giving the disk a label. I use GParted to assign disk labels but it's not for the faint of heart and over-kill because it can delete partitions.

A simpler program to set disk labels would be [e2label](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-modify-partition-labels-command-to-change-diskname/) which works on EXT2, EXT3 and EXT4 file systems. I'm sure there are many more easy to use utilities out there.

(I'm not sure how you named your partitions, but disk label is the way to go for the names to appear in launcher and nautilus).

Comment: Didn't he say he named the partitions already?

Comment: Yes he did which made me delete my original answer after rereading his question. Then I double checked using GParted and sure enough the volume label controls what appears. I undeleted my answer and added the last sentence "(I'm not sure how you named your partions...)" Therefore his method of naming the partitions was not through the low level disk/partition label.